# MySQL function work fine in MySQL database managers like (Toad) but not in java

Tags: java, mysql, toad, workbench

I wrote mysql function and it works fine in Toad/ MySQL workbench/ Heidi. But it gives following syntax error

> Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE FUNCTION FindAcid ( cust_id_in VARCHAR(20) )RETURNS VARCHAR(20) BEGIN DEC' at line 1

Below is my query sample:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS FindAcid; 
            CREATE FUNCTION FindAcid ( cust_id_in VARCHAR(20) ) 
            RETURNS VARCHAR(20) 
            BEGIN 
                 DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE; 
                 DECLARE div_val VARCHAR(128); 
                 DECLARE for_acid VARCHAR(16); 
                 DECLARE divval VARCHAR(128); 
                 DECLARE rtnforacid  VARCHAR(16); 
                 DECLARE scheme_type VARCHAR(10); 
                 DECLARE rtn VARCHAR(10); 
                 DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR 
                 SELECT (appDiv.clr_bal_amt_lkr /(SELECT SUM(COALESCE(appSum.CLR_BAL_AMT_LKR, 0)) AS PORTPOLIO FROM app_dms_daily appSum WHERE appSum.cust_id = appDiv.cust_id GROUP BY appDiv.cust_id )) AS DIV_VAL, schm_type AS SCHM_TYPE, FORACID AS FORACID 
                 FROM app_dms_daily appDiv 
                 WHERE appDiv.cust_id = cust_id_in 
                 ORDER BY DIV_VAL DESC; 
                 DECLARE cur_acid CURSOR FOR 
                 SELECT DISTINCT(COALESCE(foracid, '--')) AS EE 
                 FROM app_dms_daily 
                 WHERE CLR_BAL_AMT_LKR = (SELECT MAX(CLR_BAL_AMT_LKR) FROM app_dms_daily maxapp WHERE maxapp.CUST_ID = cust_id_in AND maxapp.SCHM_TYPE = 'ODA'); 
                 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE; 
            OPEN cur; 
            OPEN cur_acid; 
            read_loop: LOOP 
            FETCH  cur INTO div_val, scheme_type, for_acid; 
            IF done THEN 
                 LEAVE read_loop; 
            END IF; 
            END LOOP; 
            if div_val >= 0.3 AND scheme_type = 'ODA' then 
            read_loop_acid: LOOP 
            FETCH  cur_acid INTO rtn; 
            IF done THEN 
                 LEAVE read_loop_acid; 
            END IF; 
            END LOOP; 
            SET rtnforacid = rtn; 
            end if; 
            CLOSE cur; 
            CLOSE cur_acid; 
            RETURN rtnforacid; 
            END;

SELECT FindAcid('300315759');
```

Here is my java code

```
String query ="DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS FindAcid; "
            + "CREATE FUNCTION FindAcid ( cust_id_in VARCHAR(20) ) "
            + "RETURNS VARCHAR(20) "
            + "BEGIN "
            + "DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE; "
            + "DECLARE div_val VARCHAR(128); "
            + "DECLARE for_acid VARCHAR(16); "
            + "DECLARE divval VARCHAR(128); "
            + "DECLARE rtnforacid  VARCHAR(16); "
            + "DECLARE scheme_type VARCHAR(10); "
            + "DECLARE rtn VARCHAR(10); "
            + "DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR "
            + "SELECT (appDiv.clr_bal_amt_lkr /(SELECT SUM(COALESCE(appSum.CLR_BAL_AMT_LKR, 0)) AS PORTPOLIO FROM app_dms_daily appSum WHERE appSum.cust_id = appDiv.cust_id GROUP BY appDiv.cust_id )) AS DIV_VAL, schm_type AS SCHM_TYPE, FORACID AS FORACID "
            + "FROM app_dms_daily appDiv "
            + "WHERE appDiv.cust_id = cust_id_in "
            + "ORDER BY DIV_VAL DESC; "
            + "DECLARE cur_acid CURSOR FOR "
            + "SELECT DISTINCT(COALESCE(foracid, '--')) AS EE "
            + "FROM app_dms_daily "
            + "WHERE CLR_BAL_AMT_LKR = (SELECT MAX(CLR_BAL_AMT_LKR) FROM app_dms_daily maxapp WHERE maxapp.CUST_ID = cust_id_in AND maxapp.SCHM_TYPE = 'ODA'); "
            + "DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE; "
            + "OPEN cur; "
            + "OPEN cur_acid; "
            + "read_loop: LOOP "
            + "FETCH  cur INTO div_val, scheme_type, for_acid; "
            + "IF done THEN "
            + "LEAVE read_loop; "
            + "END IF; "
            + "END LOOP; "
            + "if div_val >= 0.3 AND scheme_type = 'ODA' then "
            + "read_loop_acid: LOOP "
            + "FETCH  cur_acid INTO rtn; "
            + "IF done THEN "
            + "LEAVE read_loop_acid; "
            + "END IF; "
            + "END LOOP; "
            + "SET rtnforacid = rtn; "
            + "end if; "
            + "CLOSE cur; "
            + "CLOSE cur_acid; "
            + "RETURN rtnforacid; "
            + "END;";

    getJdbcTemplate().execute(query);
```

Comment: Use two statements.  Drop the function if it exists.  Then do the `create` in another call.

Comment: Please add the java lines that cause your problem.
an idea, just base on the error message you get, is that the line breaks are not set correctly (the one before RETURNS is missing in error message). If you just add strings, one per line, don't forget the \n before line ending.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you it worked

Answer (score 0):

You didn't paste Java code so I'm guesssing from your exception that you've made something like this when creating string with sql:

```
"CREATE FUNCTION FindAcid ( cust_id_in VARCHAR(20) )" + 
"RETURNS VARCHAR(20)" + 
"BEGIN" + ...
```

You have to add space charakters to end of lines:

```
"CREATE FUNCTION FindAcid ( cust_id_in VARCHAR(20) ) " + 
"RETURNS VARCHAR(20) " + 
"BEGIN " + ...
```

Comment: I added my java code sample it is same to your answer but no positive result

Comment: Use two separate statements as @Gordon suggested.